# How to query if a property exists with typeORM and postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

At my nest server with typeORM and postgreSQL I have the endpoint getAllListing. This endpoint has an optional query param called specialDiscounts that is of type `string['veteran', 'military', first responders']`

If specialDiscounts has any string value inside I need to filter my listings based on its property pricingModel.specialDiscounts
This is an example of a listing object:

```
 {
        "id": "BmGINlCycw8miqGTH-FXu",
        "experienceName": "Fishing",
        "experienceType": "Catch that fish of a lifetime",
        "description": "come fish the biggest fish",
        "createdAt": "2023-07-22T16:46:35.677Z",
        ...
        "media": [],
        "pricingModel": {
            "id": "s4GOoMAyDdrWfvMPEh7IZ",
            "type": "public",
            "pricePerTrip": "800",
            "specialDiscounts": {
                "firstResponders": 10,
                "Veteran": 20,
                "Military": 30
            },
            "paymentMethod": [
                "credit",
                "cash"
            ],
            "cancelationPolicy": "Full refund if canceled 48 hours prior to the trip.",
            "hasIcharterBid": true,
            "minBid": 50,
            "maxBid": 200,
            "createdAt": "2023-07-23T01:02:53.485Z"
        },
        ...
    },
```

This is the service.ts of my getAllListings endpoint:

```
  async getAllListings(searchParams: ListingSearchParams) {
    let query = this.listingRepository.createQueryBuilder('listing')
     ...

    //I do a left join here to acces the pricing model table (the relations are ok)
    .leftJoinAndSelect('listing.pricingModel', 'pricingModel')
    ...
    .orderBy('listing.createdAt', 'DESC')

    const { 
      ...
      specialDiscounts, 
      fishingTechniques, 
      targetedSpecies, 
      captains 
    } = searchParams;

   ...

    //I tried this option but it is returning empty array always

    if(specialDiscounts && specialDiscounts.length > 0) {
     const discountsToSearch = specialDiscounts.map((discount) => {
     if(discount.toLowerCase() === 'first responders'){
    return 'CAST(pricingModel.specialDiscounts ->> \'firstResponders\' AS INTEGER) IS NOT NULL'
    } else if (discount.toLowerCase() === 'military'){
    return 'CAST(pricingModel.specialDiscounts ->> \'military\' AS INTEGER) IS NOT NULL'
    } else if (discount.toLowerCase() === 'veteran'){
    return 'CAST(pricingModel.specialDiscounts ->> \'veteran\' AS INTEGER) IS NOT NULL'    }
      });
      query.andWhere(discountsToSearch.join(' OR '));
    }


   ...

    const listings = await query.getMany();
    return listings;
```

}

At my pricingModel entity the specialDiscounts column is of type json:

```
export type PricingModelDiscounts = {
  veteran: number;
  military: number;
  firstResponders: number;
};

@Entity('pricingModel')
export class PricingModel {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  ...

  @Column({
    type: 'json',
    nullable: true,
  })
  specialDiscounts: PricingModelDiscounts;

...
```

I am trying to compare if strings of the specialDiscounts exists at the json object pricingModel.specialDiscounts but I am not sure how to do this query with typeORM and postgreSQL

Comment: Getting more understanding about issue, 'veteran', 'military', first responders' can be null?